# Python csv reader // how to ignore enclosing char (because sometimes it's missing)

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to import csv data from files where sometimes the enclosing char " is missing.

So I have rows like this:

```
"ThinkPad";"2000.00";"EUR"
"MacBookPro";"2200.00;EUR"  
# In the second row the closing " after 2200.00 is missing
# also the closing " before EUR" is missing
```

Now I am reading the csv data with this:

```
csv.reader(
            codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1'),
            delimiter=";",
            dialect=csv.excel_tab)
```

And the data I get for the second row is this:

["MacBookPro", "2200.00;EUR"]

Aside from pre-processing my csv files with a unix command like sed and removing all closing chars " and relying on the semicolon to seperate the columns, what else can I do?

Comment: Not sure if that would help but you can also automatically add the missings `"` in your csv?

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer. Yes, I could add missing closing chars. That's an option.

Comment: You could load without qualifiers, then strip out the ". str.replace('"','')

Comment: You could change the quotechar. But the problem is that whatever is producing your `csv` is **producing a broken CSV**.

Comment: You can check the number of columns, and if they are less than expected, remove quotes for that row and try parsing it again. If the number of columns is what is expected, use those new values. This is a hack, but you seem to be out of control of the program creating the CSV.

Comment: @quasoft Good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *might* work:

```
import csv
import io

file = io.StringIO(u'''
"ThinkPad";"2000.00";"EUR"
"MacBookPro";"2200.00;EUR"
'''.strip())

reader = csv.reader((line.replace('"', '') for line in file), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

The problem is that if there are any legitimate quoted line, e.g.

```
"MacBookPro;Awesome Edition";"2200.00";"EUR"
```

Or, worse:

```
"MacBookPro:
Description: Awesome Edition";"2200.00";"EUR"
```

Your output is going to produce too few/many columns. But if you *know* that's not a problem then it will work fine. You could pre-screen the file by adding this before the read part, which would give you the malformed line:

```
for line in file:
    if line.count(';') != 2:
        raise ValueError('No! This file has broken data on line {!r}'.format(line))
file.seek(0)
```

Or alternatively you could screen as you're reading:

```
for row in reader:
if any(';' in _ for _ in row):
    print('Error:')
print(row)
```

Ultimately your best option is to fix whatever is producing your garbage csv file.

Comment: Wayne, actually I'm processing csv exports of account statements from a bank. So I can't fix the source data ;) But excellent answer!

Comment: You are using a generator comprehension to remove all enclosing chars (that is: ") and then tell the csv.reader that you have a quotechar=' " '?

Comment: I would contact your bank about fixing their CSV exports because that's suuuper janky. The fact that your *bank* is generating incorrect data is kind of worrisome. And yeah, `quotechar='"'` is superfluous if you're removing it already. Also note that the best way to say that an answer is useful is with an upvote (and possibly accept, if it actually solves your problem)

Comment: Can't upvote unfortunately. Not enough reputation. But accepted your answer. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping through all the lines/rows of the file, you can use string's .replace() function to get rid off the quotes (if you don't need them later-on for other purposes.).

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     my_file = csv.reader(codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1')
...       delimiter=";",
...       dialect=csv.excel_tab)
...     )
...     for row in my_file:
...         (model,price,currency) = row
...         model.replace('"','')
...         price.replace('"','')
...         currency.replace('"','')v
...         print 'Model is: %s (costs %s%s).' % (model,price,currency)
>>> 
Model is: MacBookPro (costs 2200.00EUR).
```

Comment: It *looks* like you tried this, but I can't tell how, because `.replace` and `.split` are string methods and csv readers return lists.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it really. I went based on your question where the data is listed as string. You're right the csv reader returns information as lists. Possible solution could be using .join(). Let me post addition to my answer..

Comment: Why are you using `csv.reader` when in the end you do all of your parsing manually? `for row in csvfile` would work just fine.

Comment: You shouldn't use `.join()` either - that's parsing, unparsing, and then parsing the data again. Don't do that.